# PHP auto increment number on form submit

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a script which calculates a quote based on values within database.

I need a simple bit of PHP code to show  a number and add 1 to it each time the form is submitted.

For example, Joe Bloggs gets a quote, and quote reference number 111 is shown on gthe screen.

The next time the form is submitted it will show 112 on screen and so on.

What is the best code to use to achieve this?

Comment: can you post what you did/tried ??

Comment: Perhaps you want a column in your database's quotes table that auto-increments?  PHP would just read the value from the column and trust mysql to do the right thing.

Comment: When showing all the comments on the page, you may increment a variable to each results.

Comment: I think you'll want to use an auto-increment column in the quotes table and only show the number to the user after they've submitted the form (and the row is added to the table). Use [lastInsertId()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

Answer (score 2):

You should really think about an auto-increment id column in your database.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

As an alternative you can write the number into a file with php...

Answer (score 0):

PHP has **nothing** to do with `AUTO_INCREMENT` MySQL attribute.

Just apply `AUTO_INCREMENT` to field you want and when inserting data, insert data to every field except `AUTO_INCREMENT` fields. MySQL will do that automatically for you.

To display latest number of your `AUTO_INCREMENT` field - use [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) or see [this article](http://zenverse.net/php-mysql-next-auto-increment-value/).